# Combine multiple values within foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I want to be able combine the 2 if statements below within the foreach into 1 variable
which will be variable $propertyCodeMerged.  Basically, there will be in instance where both of the if/else if conditions will be true so I want $propertyCode1 and $propertyCode2 merged into 1 variable.  This must include duplicates as well. How should I go about doing this?
I got this working for just 1 condition but having trouble accounting for multiple conditions.  Any pointers would help.

```
$propertyCode1 = "":
$propertyCode2 = "":
$propertyCodeMerged = "";

$propGrid = @=grid;
foreach($propGrid as $property){
   $code = $property['property_code']; 
   $wo_type_id = $property['id'];
   if($code != "" && $property['complete'] == "Yes" && $property['photos'] == "Yes"){
      $propertyCode1 .= "'$code', ";
  } else if ($code != "" && $property['complete'] == "Yes" && $property['id'] == "20"){
      $propertyCode2 .= "'$code', ";
  }
}
if($propertyCodeMerged != "")
$propertyCodeMerged = substr($propertyCodeMerged, 0, -2);
```

Example:
Here is an example output of @=grid:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [property_code] => TESTCODE-01 [street] => 100 Fake Street 
[city] => Detroit [state] => MI [zip] => [county] => [id] => 20 [type_name_label] => Inspection 
[other_fee] => 0.00 [down_pay] => [monthly_pay] => [phone] => [resolve] => No 
[date_completed] => [photos] => Yes [report] => No [complete] => Yes [reorder] => No ) )
```

So essentially, everytime a user checks the "complete" and "photos" checkboxes, it records as a "Yes".  So only property codes/rows with those 2 checkboxes marked Yes will get assigned to $propertyCode1.

Here is how I had with 1 condition:

```
$propertyCode = "";
$propGrid = @=grid;
foreach($propGrid as $property){
   $code = $property['property_code']; 
   $wo_type_id = $property['id'];
   if($code != "" && $property['complete'] == "Yes" && $property['photos'] == "Yes"){
      $propertyCode .= "'$code', ";
  }
}
if($propertyCode != "")
$propertyCode = substr($propertyCode, 0, -2);
```

So if there were 5 property codes but only 3 had the complete and photos checkboxes marked, $propertyCode should have something like: TESTCODE-01, TESTCODE-02, TESTCODE-03.
What I want to do now is try to include the logic above but also add another condition for when there are propertycodes/rows that only has the complete checkbox marked and has an id of "20".

In other words, I want to combine that 1 condition example above to this below:

```
$propertyCode = "";
$propGrid = @=grid;
foreach($propGrid as $property){
   $code = $property['property_code']; 
   $wo_type_id = $property['id'];
   if($code != "" && $property['complete'] == "Yes" && $property['id'] == "20"){
      $propertyCode .= "'$code', ";
  }
}
if($propertyCode != "")
$propertyCode = substr($propertyCode, 0, -2);
```

Comment: What is `$propGrid = @=grid;` supposed to do?

Comment: `$propertyCodeMerged` looks like it always `== ""`.

Comment: What you're trying to do here is really quite unclear. Would you mind clarifying what you're doing?

Comment: @MarkBaker its from web app called processmaker. Its basically assigning an associative array of associative arrays to $propGrid. I can provide an example of the array if you'd like

Comment: @Zarathuztra hey i edited my original post. I tried to clarify best I can without going too overboard.  Let me know if that helps any.

Comment: @Zarathuztra i think I figured it out. Seems like a simple concat line did it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$propertyCode1 = "":
$propertyCode2 = "":
$propertyCodeMerged = "";

$propGrid = @=grid;
foreach($propGrid as $property){
   $code = $property['property_code']; 
   $wo_type_id = $property['id'];
   if($code != "" && $property['complete'] == "Yes" && $property['photos'] == "Yes"){
      $propertyCode1 .= "'$code', ";
  } else if ($code != "" && $property['complete'] == "Yes" && $property['id'] == "20"){
      $propertyCode2 .= "'$code', ";
  }
}
//added this line
$propertyCodeMerged = $propertyCode1 . $propertyCode2;

if($propertyCodeMerged != "")
$propertyCodeMerged = substr($propertyCodeMerged, 0, -2);
```